# javascript change div html when click span

Tags: javascript, onclick, html

Ok I have a small question.

I have the following

```
<div><span class="spanright" onclick"">Update</span><label class="myinfo"><b>Business information:</b></label></div>
```

What I want to do is when the user clicks on the span it changes the html after the label an adds an input box and submit button.

I think I need to do a `this.document` but not sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi hope this might give you a small understanding of what to do when it comes to registering events. StackOverflow is about you learning how to do something, so we dont write the scripts for you, we are just trying to point you in the right direction of it.

http://jsfiddle.net/WKWFZ/2/

I would recommend you to import jQuery library, as done in the example, if possible. It makes the the world of javascript alot easier!

Documentation to look up:

http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/

http://api.jquery.com/bind/

Look up some jQuery tutorials! there is alot of them out there.

Answer (score 0):

I added a form which will hold the input

JavaScript:

```
function showInput()
{
    document.getElementById('container').innerHTML += '<input type="text"/><input type="submit"/>';
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <span class="spanright" onclick"showInput()">Update</span>
    <label class="myinfo"><b>Business information:</b></label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Summoner's answer is right, but I prefer using jquery (it's loaded on almost every page I work with):

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <span class="spanright">Update</span>
    <label class="container"><b>Business information:</b></label>
</div>​
```

Javascript:

```
​$(".spanright").click(function(){
    $("#container").append('<br /><input type="text"/><input type="submit"/>');
    $(".spanright").unbind('click');
})​​;​
```

This way, the click event will work once, as it is what you probably intended.

Answer (score -1):

Try this in jquery flavor --

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".spanright").click(function(){
    $(".myinfo").css("color","red");

    });
});
```

Check fiddle --

http://jsfiddle.net/swapnesh/yHRND/